# Change status when bot joins server | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, status

In the status of my discord bot, it says in how many servers its in, but how can i refresh it when the bot joins a server? I think i have to put it under:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
```

But i dont know how.
This is my status command:

```
async def chng_pr():
  await client.wait_until_ready()

  statuses = [f"-help | {len(client.guilds)} servers", f"-setup | {len(client.guilds)} servers", f"-vote | {len(client.guilds)} servers", f"-patreon | {len(client.guilds)} servers"]

  while not client.is_closed():
    status = random.choice(statuses)

    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(status))

    await asyncio.sleep(120)

client.loop.create_task(chng_pr())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `chng_pr` function will loop every two minutes, so it's kinda useless to change the presence when a bot joins a guild. But if you really want you can delete that while loop and call it when the bot joins a guild. If you also want it to look every 2 minutes you can use `discord.ext.tasks`.

Here's how you should change the function.

```py
async def chng_pr():
    """Changes presences"""
    statuses = [f"-help | {len(client.guilds)} servers", f"-setup | {len(client.guilds)} servers", f"-vote | {len(client.guilds)} servers", f"-patreon | {len(client.guilds)} servers"]

    status = random.choice(statuses)

    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(status))
```

Here's how to change the presence when the bot joins a guild.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    await chng_pr()
```

Here's how to make a task and run in on the `on_ready` event

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(minutes=2)
async def change_presence():
    """Will loop every two minutes and change presences"""
    await chng_pr()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    # Starting the loop
    change_presence.start()
```

You can also make it to be used in a command.

Note: This needs `intents.guilds`

Comment: lmao I answered 3 of 5 of your questions on stackoverflow and you didn't event accept one.

Comment: sorry, didnt know how to. i did it now :)